# Add a Soap Zeep Header with a potencial kwarg problem

Tags: python, soap, request, zeep

So, I'm developing a function with a SOAP request using ZEEP 3.4 and I need to add a header, actually I tried everything, my last option is using the Number #3 of [Zeep Headers documentation](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/headers.html) but I'm having a big problem using this part:

```
header_value = header(username='mvantellingen')
```

because the Element that needs to be created and set the value has a "-"
This name is "LAN-ApplicationName" and when I try to use

```
 header_value = header(LAN-ApplicationName='TEST')
```

the console says:
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Maybe there is another option. I will send a pic of config who works in SOAPui app

[This is how the request is config in SOAPui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH1Iq.png)

Thx by advance.

Adding some pics and i will send my python code.
[image: SOAPui Raw]
[image: SOAPui XML]

```
 session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth('*********', '********') #Password of the company 
client = Client('https://minutaservices.lancargo.com/CreateEminuta-3.0.0-ws/CreateEminuta-3.0.0?wsdl', transport=Transport(session=session))

#header = client.get_element('{http://ws.latam.com/v3_0}CreateEminutaRS')
header = xsd.Element(
'{http://ws.latam.com/v3_0}CreateEminutaRS',
xsd.ComplexType([
    xsd.Element(
        '{http://ws.latam.com/v3_0}LAN-ApplicationName',
        xsd.String()),
])
)

#header_value = header(LAN-ApplicationName='TEST')

result = client.service.createEminuta(
        {#ClientList
            "Client":{"Type":"",
                    "ContacInformation":{"Name":{"lastName":"teste"}},
                    "isPayer":""
                    }

        },
        {#Document
            "CargoBillingLists":{"CargoBilling":{"type":"",
                                                 "DocumentInformation":{"number":"", "emissionDate":""},
                                                 "Amount":{"totalValue":""}
                                                }
                                },
            "Insurance":{"type":"",

                        },
            "Location":{"isoCountryCode":"teste",
                        "StationIata":{"origin":"","destination":""}
                       },
            "AditionaIInfo":{"isMultiModal":"",
                             "comercialProduct":""


                            }           

        },
        {#Cargo
            "PackingList":{"Packing":{"Package":{"Identificator":{"code":"", "description":""}

                                                },
                                     "Pieces":{"quatity":"", "weight":""}
                                    }
                          },
            "Collect":{"deliveryCode":"",
                       "code":"",
                       "Attendant":{"person":"", "department":""},
                       "Requester":{"department":"", "person":""},
                       "TimeRange":{"initial":"", "final":""},
                       "AditionalInfo":{"isLobbyAccepts":"","isCloseLunchTime":"","isHourLobby":""}
                      },
            "Treatment":{"Commodity":{"code":"",
                                      "name":"",
                                      "groupCode":"", 
                                      "groupName":"",                                          
                                     }
                        }
        },
        {#Payment
            "form":""
        }, #_soapheaders=[header_value]
    )
print(result)
return 'teste'
```

Comment: hi, whats the `header` server expect can you show us?

Comment: Hi,when I try request, the server answer this: {
    'CargoDocumentId': None,
    'Error': None,
    'ServiceStatus': {
        'code': -1,
        'message': 'HTTP Header LAN-ApplicationName / LATAM-ApplicationName not defined.',
        'nativeMessage': 'HTTP Header LAN-ApplicationName / LATAM-ApplicationName not defined.'
    }
} and i already have config in program SOAPui like in the photo in the post (This is how the request is config in SOAPui) when i config like this, in the SOAPui works

Comment: can you show us the raw xml header that the soapui sends which server is accepting?

Comment: I added some pics of SOAPui and post my own python code, remember i need help only in the code, the SOAPui is just for examples